# Search pandas column and return all elements (rows) that contain any (one or more) non-digit character

Tags: regex, pandas, search

Seems pretty straight forward. The column contains numbers in general but for some reason, some of them have non-digit characters. I want to find all of them. I am using this code:

```
df_other_values.total_count.str.contains('[^0-9]')
```

but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use 
np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

So I tried this:

```
df_other_values = df_other.total_countvalues
df_other_values.total_count.str.contains('[^0-9]')
```

but get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'total_countvalues'
```

So instead of going down the rabbit hole further, I was thinking there must be a way to do this without having to change my dataframe into a np.object. Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need cast to `string`s first by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df_other_values.total_count.astype(str).str.contains('[^0-9]')]
```

Alternative solution with [`isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html):

```
df1 = df[~df_other_values.total_count.astype(str).str.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: Thanks. That returns a Boolean list. To be more specific, how do I return the actual contents where the condition is True?

Comment: Thanks. That work. I had a typo above. So this worked. "df1 = df_other[~df_other.total_count.astype(str).str.isnumeric()]"